# run 2 Python Cloud Functions in same script

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a script with 2 Cloud Functions, lets say Fn1 and Fn2. Fn1 is event driven, gets the uri of a storage object, Fn2 is required to take the uri from Fn1 and use this as input.
I have tested Fn1 and Fn2 independently and they work.

What I need is how to run both functions together in one go, so that Fn1 gets the information needed and passes it to Fn2 to execute and provide the final output.

```
def fn1(a,b):
    value = '{}.'format(a['x'])
    return value

def fn2(value):
    do work
    output = final
```

1.) I want to be able to deploy both functions in a single Cloud Function (Or maybe 2).

2.) I want to be able to have Fn1 triggered by event(Solved, working OK), but call Fn2 on completion and have Fn2 output final result.

As you may have noticed, I am early on in the Python adoption, so not so great with ability currently, but learning fast.

Comment: I didn't catch if fn2 need to be called by an event (included an HTTP request, I mean to be deployed as a Cloud Functions), or if fn2 is only called by fn1 "internally" in your code. Can you detail this part?

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere, thank you sir for responding to the question. fn2 will be internal to the code, and will only ever be called by fn1. fn1 will be event triggered using google.storage.object.finalize. The fn1 gets the url of an uploaded object, then calls fn2 (Vision API) to process said object, supplying the returned url as input. Sounds trivial, but for a newbie like me, has made me question the meaning of life! :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how you trigger these functions (http/pubsub)...

I have http function that I trigger from HTTP but in payload I define what script should do.

Here is a little snippet of it:

```
# to run locally:
# FLASK_ENV=development FLASK_APP=main flask run
# and uncomment the following:
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def wrapper():
    return main(request)
```

and main function is like this:

```py
def main(args=None):
    action = args.form['action'] #simplified because I use it together with argparse 

    match action:
        case 'task1':
            ...
```

This can be done with pubsub too, you can use pubsub attribute to define what action of the function should do.

You can not have same function to be triggered from http and pubsub.

As for second question, you have GCP workflows or GCP composer but these products might be overkill for what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks you for looking into this and providing a response, the first function is triggered by a storage event "finalize". Upon uploading an object, once finalized, the function will get triggered. I understand I can specify a value to return in fn1 and then call fn2 from fn1, passing through the returned value as input to fn2. I was hoping this way, the storage event trigger will run fn1 and fn2.

Comment: yes, you could call a function within a function. from python SDK you could trigger func2

https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudfunctions/latest/functions_v1/types.html

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions means that you expose only one function during your deployment. However, in your code, you can have several functions, classes, files, object,(...), there is no issue with that. The only condition is: only one entry point in your code.

Therefore, you can have do something like that

```
def fn3(c):
  do.other.things(c)

def fn2(e):
  do.something(e)

def fn1(event, context):
  doFn2(event)
  doFn3(context)
  print("end")
```

Deploy with the `--entry-point=fn1` parameter to specify which first function to call and then build your workload around.